# How to prove that for $\forall n, a_0 = 1, a_n :=\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1} + \frac{2}{a_{n-1}}): a_n^2\geq2$?

Tags: analysis

Hey I have a problem in one of my course on which I spent a few hours, but I just cant figure out how to prove it.
I have a sequence of numbers $a_n$ which is defined as follows:

\begin{align}
a_0 &= 1\\
a_n &:=\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1} + \frac{2}{a_{n-1}})
\end{align}
and I need to prove that $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N_+}: a_n^2 \geq 2$

Since the sequence is defined recursively I tried proving this with induction, so far I have this:
\begin{align}
a_1^2 &= 2.25 \geq 2\\
\end{align}
Now chose a fix $n$ so that $a_n^2$ then $a_{n+1}^2 \geq 2$
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}^2 &= \frac{1}{4}(a_n + \frac{2}{a_n})^2\\
&= \frac{1}{4}(a_n^2 + \frac{4a_n}{a_n} + \frac{4}{a_n^2})\\
&\geq 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{4}{4a_n^2}
\end{align}

But at this point I don't see how I can get something greater than 2.
I also tried using 2 $n$'s: $n : a_n^2 \geq 2 \land a_{n+1}^2 \geq 2$.
The formula got more complicated but I still could not see a way to prove it.

Is there some trick I have to use to prove this?
Thanks for all the help in advance :)

Comment: Using the AM-GM inequality it is $x+\frac 2x \ge 2 \sqrt{x\cdot \frac 2x}=2\sqrt 2,$ for any positive real number $x.$ Can you get your result from here?

Comment: Should be $$= \frac{1}{4}\left(a_n^2 + \frac{4a_n}{a_n} + \frac{\color{red}4}{a_n^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f : x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{2}\left(x + \dfrac{2}{x} \right)$ is differentiable over $(0, +\infty)$ and for all $x > 0$,
$$f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(1 - \dfrac{2}{x^2} \right)$$

So $f'(x) > 0 \Longleftrightarrow x^2 > 2 \Longleftrightarrow x> \sqrt{2}$, so $f$ is decreasing over $(0, \sqrt{2}]$ and increasing over $[\sqrt{2}, +\infty)$. In particular, $f$ attains a minimum on $(0, +\infty)$ at $x_0 = \sqrt{2}$ and this minimum is $f(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}$.

So for all $x > 0$, $f(x) \geq \sqrt{2}$.

Now, since $a_n > 0$ for all $n \geq 0$ (easily proven by induction), one has, for all $n > 0$, $a_n = f(a_{n-1}) \geq \sqrt{2}$, i.e. $$\boxed{a_n^2 \geq 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

We know for all $x,y \quad x+y\ge 2\sqrt{xy}$.

Then,  replace $x,y$ by $a_n \quad and \quad \frac{2}{a_n}$, we have $a_n+\frac{2}{a_n}\ge2\sqrt{a_n\times \frac{2}{a_n} } \Longrightarrow (a_n + \frac{2}{a_n})^2\ge 8$.

In your way \begin{align}
a_{n+1}^2 &= \frac{1}{4}(a_n + \frac{2}{a_n})^2\\
&\ge  \frac{1}{4}\times 8\\&\ge2
\end{align}

Finaly $a_{n+1}^2\ge 2$

Answer (score 0):

*In the same spirit as @TheSilverDoe.*

Make the problem more general and rewrite
$$a_n=\frac{1}{2} \left(a_{n-1}+\frac{k}{a_{n-1}}\right)\qquad\text{with}\qquad a_0=1\qquad\text{and}\qquad k >1$$ as
$$a_n=a_{n-1}-\frac{a_{n-1}^2 -k}{2 a_{n-1}}$$ to recognize Newton iterative scheme for solving $a^2=k$ starting with an initial guess $a_0=1$.

Considering the function $f(x)=x^2-k$, we have
$$f(1)=1-k\qquad\text{and}\qquad f''(1)=2\qquad\implies\qquad f(1)\times f''(1)=2(1-k)~<~0$$

So, by [Darbous theorem](http://www.numdam.org/item/NAM_1869_2_8__17_0.pdf), the first iterate will be an overestimate (the only one) of the solution which then will reach the solution from above and, for sure, the same for $x^2$.

*Just for your curiosity*

There is a closed form
$$a_n=\sqrt{k} \coth \left(2^n \coth ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\right)=\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{2^{-n}}{\coth
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)}\right)$$

Answer (score -1):

$$a_{n}^2 - 2 = \frac{1}{4}\left(a_{n-1} + \frac{2}{a_{n-1}}\right)^2 - 2\\
= \frac{a_{n-1}^2 }{4} + 1 + \frac{4}{a_{n-1}^2} - 2 \\
= \frac{a_{n-1}^2 }{4} - 1 + \frac{1}{a_{n-1}^2} + \frac{3}{a_{n-1}^2}s\\
= \left(\frac{a_{n-1} }{2} - \frac{1}{a_{n-1}}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{a_{n-1}^2} \geq0$$
So we have:
$$a_{n}^2 - 2 \geq 0 \implies a_{n}^2 \geq 2$$

Comment: You are doing an induction without using the induction hypothesis in the induction step...

Comment: Yeah you're right. I guess the "Inductive step" portion would be a proof in it's own right because it doesn't depend on the inductive hypothesis.